# Integration of breeze with mob-x

Tags: breeze, mobx

Is there a way to make these two work together? Can I make breeze create @observable properties on the entities it creates?

Comment: It seems that nobody here is familiar with breeze. Could you provide more context so people can help?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?